# Recover JSON array field to a byte array in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring and here I am sending an http request which needs to pass a message to server. But the message should be sent as a byte array. I use the following curl command. Here the message passed is "hello".

```
curl -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"message":[72,69,76,76,79]}' http://localhost:8080/json
```

Controller should listen to the request and recover the message field to a byte[] again. 
Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> jsonReceiver(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {

    String bytes = request.get("message").toString();

    LOGGER.info("Message: {}", bytes);
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    response.put("status-code", "1000");
    response.put("success", "true");

    HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    respHeaders.add("Pragma", "ack");
    return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, respHeaders, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);}
```

Here I can get the output as an string. But I want to get it to a byte[].
Is there any way to get this as a byte array from controller without reading as a string and then manipulating it.

```
Message: [72,69,76,76,79]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `byte[]` from a `String` like this:

```
byte[] byteArray = bytes.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you get the request body as a `Map<String, Object>` the only way to get your byte array is to parse the "stringyfied" byte array and build the resultant byte array.

Something like:

```
String byteArrayAsStr = request.get("message").toString();

// First get only the "string-numeric" values (storing them into a String[]
String[] byteValues = byteArrayAsStr.substring(1, byteArrayAsStr.length() - 1).split(",");
byte[] messageBytes = new byte[byteValues.length];

// then we store each parsed byte value into our result byte[] (messageBytes)
for (int i=0, len=messageBytes.length; i<len; i++) {
   messageBytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(byteValues[i].trim()); // trim not necessary in your case, as you send your array without spaces after commas 
}
[...]
```

That's the way to do it if you cannot find a better approach to get the request body directly in the wanted type (using appropriate DTOs).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String message  = "[72,69,76,76,79]";
String[] stringArray = message.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");
byte[] byteArray = new byte[stringArray.length];

for(int i = 0; i<stringArray.length; i++)
{
    byteArray[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
}
```

First you convert to an array of strings. Then you iterate in that array and for each element you converto to int then cast to byte and assign it to the byte array.